# How do I convert numbers to a format like &H4998

Tags: vb.net, numbers, short, unsigned-integer

I have some source code like this:

```
If p.Type = &H1 Then
v = p.Value(0).ToString()
ElseIf p.Type = &H2 Then
```

I want to get the function to print out each 'p.Type' to the console (before the testing) but they print out as simple numbers (1134, or 56, etc.).
Intellisense tells me the &H1 is an unsigned integer and the p.Type is declared as a short.
How would I get the Console.Writeline to show them in the format with the ampersand and H?

Thank you in advance.

```
Friend Function DisplayHexNumber(ByVal inputvalue As UInt32, Optional ByVal asbasic As Boolean = True) As String

    Dim bulb As String = "Error"
    Try
        bulb = Hex(inputvalue)
        If asbasic = True Then
            bulb = "&H" & bulb.ToString
        Else
            bulb = "0x" & bulb.ToString.PadLeft(4, "0")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    Return bulb
End Function
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/963zt96e(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks, Mitch. Honored. :) Let me try a few of these. May just convert the code to not use this notation (replace with human readable values)

Comment: Here is what I used to get a nice console output. 'code' Friend Function DisplayHexNumber(ByVal inputvalue As UInt32, Optional ByVal asbasic As Boolean = True) As String

        Dim bulb As String = "Error"
        Try
            bulb = Hex(inputvalue)
            If asbasic = True Then
                bulb = "&H" & bulb.ToString.PadLeft(4, "0")
            Else
                bulb = "0x" & bulb.ToString.PadLeft(4, "0")
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        Return bulb
    End Function

Answer (score 1):

There is no "format with the ampersand and H".  That is just how VB represents hexadecimal literals.  To say that you want those numbers in the "format with the ampersand and H" is like saying that you want a `String` in the format with the double quotes.  If you want to convert an integral number (`Byte`, `Short`, `Integer`, `Long`) to a `String` in hexadecimal format rather than decimal format then you simply use the "x" or "X" specifier, e.g.

```
Dim text = number.ToString("X")
```

The only reason I can possibly think of that you would ever want to add the '&H' prefix is if you're generating VB code.  If that's what you're doing then you'd concatenate two `Strings` there in exactly the same way you would anywhere else.  Other than that, if you want to correctly identify a hexadecimal number then you should prefix it with '0x', which is how it's done in C-based languages (C++, Java, C#, etc) because that's how it's done in mathematics.

Comment: I tweaked your answer to more closely answer the original question

Comment: To say almost anything in programming today is to invite misinterpretation. For example, define 'Node'. Not really.

Comment: The reason I need this is that I have some code for extracting Metadata ... which was free... etc. Anyways, I am trying to see what is and what isn't covered by it. The purpose of the code is to format and interpret the values returned (values, properties). I knew this but it still doesn't do exactly what I needed to be able to do a visual comparison with the very long list of metadata properties.... Let me try out some of these suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is probably sufficient.

**&H is one way of specifying that the number is hexadecimal in some languages such as Visual BASIC; H is not a part of the number itself.**

I really doubt you need this part, but:

There should be many in-built ways to convert the formats of numbers, in the language you're using. If not, you can convert it yourself:

Assuming that the most significant digit is first, and the least significant digit is last (big-endian) which I believe is true in Visual BASIC:

1. Set initial values, `result = 0` and `power = 1`.
2. Get the last hex digit, converting A to F (or a to f) into 10 to 15.
3. Multiply the current digit by `power`; increment `result` by the answer.
4. Multiply `power` by 16.
5. Get the next digit from the end.
6. Repeat from 3. until there are no more digits.

Comment: P.S. I apologise on behalf of any hostile people on here! I am still learning the rules of these sites myself, and I was often surprised by hostility when I first arrived. With a little experience I've become convinced that it is a minority, and we notice them too much. If your question or my answer is inappropriate, I think the reputation system will teach us that very well, with no need for cold answers and definitely no need for hostility. Please do come back!

Comment: I still wish some of my downvotes would be explained more at the current time. I'm not offended. Haven't been here long, want to learn etc..I like the way this site lets you improve things. I like reason. I like iteration.

Comment: I get it. Thanks. So actually spitting those characters (&H49 for example) out to the console would require some custom code ... sheesh. And you are right, I didn't need to understand the fundamentals of Hex numbers... just the 'representational' quirks. :)

Comment: BTW, Thomas couldn't agree more. The world has changed, hasn't it? ZagNut’s Law: Arrogance is inversely proportional to ability.

Comment: "Thumbs up" is not quite what the up arrow is for, so I will simply say "Thumbs up smiley face". I included the overkill detail for future browsers to the site, who may be newer to programming.